# jQuery trigger click mobile Safari (iPad)

Tags: jquery, ipad, mobile-safari

I have stumbled upon a bug in Safari on iPad.

```
$('#next_proj a').trigger('click');
```

.. does not seems to click on the actual link.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be a bug. My guess is that they did not want to allow javascript emulated user clicks.

Answer (score 6):

I got this to work by doing this...

```
var el = $('#next_proj a').get(0);
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
el.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: This actually does trigger a click, but it will not work on an anchor to open a new window.. Interesting. I think Apple added a way to determine if the click is legitimate in safari's javascript engine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried triggering a touch event instead of a click event?  Not sure how you would implement in jquery - but it isn't too complicated in plain js

```
function simulateEvent() {
  var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  e.initEvent('touchstart',true, true);
  document.dispatchEvent(e);
}
```