# jquery mobile - cannot register click on data-role=content in iOS only

Tags: ios, ipad, click, jquery-mobile

I'm stuck with the following code:

```
$('div:jqmData(panel="main") div:jqmData(role="content")').live('click', function(event) {                                                                  
    hideAllPanels();
    alert ("clicked");
 });
```

where panel=main is my main content panel, containing several pages, each with it's div data-role="content". Besides the main-panel, I have a popover-panel, which I want to close once the user "clicks" somewhere outside the panel.

Works on PC, not on iPad. Could this be the same as this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543733/jquery-trigger-click-mobile-safari-ipad)? If so, maybe someone has an idea regarding a workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: which version of jquery mobile are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using beta 1, bind it to listen for vclick instead of click.
Let me know if it doesn't work.

```
$('div:jqmData(panel="main") div:jqmData(role="content")').live('vclick', function(event) {                                                                  
    hideAllPanels();
    alert ("clicked");
 });
```

Comment: works. Thanks! Another question: For beta 2+ I will have to replace all "vclicks" with "click" again, since "vclick" will be removed. Correct?

Comment: yup!.
for beta 1 you'll have to use "vclick" instead of "click"